# Automated download of file from Drive in Web App?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a polling web app that checks Google Drive and automatically downloads files without user interaction.

Using ContentService I have managed to get things working when I place the code in the doGet function.

However this only works once and there does not appear to be a way to refresh or reload the page automatically on a timer event.

Using a SetTimeout on the client side javascript I can get a function on the server side to automatically trigger at certain intervals but then I am stuck with what to do with the output from ContentService.

The on Success call back will not accept the output from createTextOutput.

My solution does not not need to be deployed and I'm happy to execute from the editor if that expands my choices.

So once I have the output from createTextOutput on my server side what am I supposed to do with it to get it back to the client in order to cause the file download?

I have included the code if that helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>

    setTimeout(
    function () 
    { 
      document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 'Event Timer';
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
        .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .fetchFromGoogleDrive();
    }, 60000);

    function onSuccess(sHTML) 
    {
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 'File Downloaded ' + sHTML;
    }

    function onFailure(error) 
    {
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = error.message;
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="results">Waiting to DownLoad!</div>
id="Fetch">Fetch!</button> 
  </body>
</html>

function doGet() { 
  Logger.log('doGet');
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function fetchFromGoogleDrive() {
  //Logger.Log('fetchFromGoogleDrive');

  var fileslist = DriveApp.searchFiles("Title contains 'Expected File'");

  if (fileslist.hasNext()) {
    //Logger.Log('File found');
    var afile = fileslist.next();
    var aname = afile.getName();
    var acontent = afile.getAs('text/plain').getDataAsString();

    var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
    output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.CSV);
    output.setContent(acontent);
    output.downloadAsFile(aname);
    return afile.getDownloadUrl();
  }
  else
  {
    //Logger.Log('No File Found');
    return 'Nothing to download';
  }

  //Logger.log('All files processed.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Different answer after clarification.

If this is intended to run automated as a webapp what I would do is return the getDownloadUrl and create a new iFrame using that that as the source.

Apps Script

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function getDownloadLink(){
  //slice removes last parameter gd=true. This needs to be removed. slice is a hack you should do something better
  return DriveApp.getFileById("0B_j9_-NbJQQDckwxMHBzeVVuMHc").getDownloadUrl().slice(0,-8); 
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
     <p id="dlBox"></p>  
  </body>

  <script>

    function buildLink(res){
      var dlBox = document.createElement("iframe");
      dlBox.src = res;      
      document.getElementById("dlBox").appendChild(dlBox)
    }

    //automate this as you need
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(buildLink)
    .getDownloadLink();    

  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: That's not the point here once or many times, or manually via a button (not shown in this example).  The point is once the function is entered there is no provided mechanism for returning the google drive document for downloading. The only workable mechanism is downloading a file via a doGet().